# limit of monotonic and limited sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

**Problem statement:** need to prove that $x_n = \frac {10}{1}*\frac{11}{3}*...*\frac{n+9}{2n-1} $
converges

**My attempt:**

1)The sequence is decreasing : $ \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}=\frac{n+10}{2n+1}$ and the limit of this equals to 1/2 which is lower than 1. So we can assume that sequence really decreases.
2)The next step is to prove the boundedness of the sequence. Actually, i know that the sequence is strictly positive and bounded from below with zero. So i can apply Weierstrass theorem on bounded increasing sequence and it will probably solve my problem. However, i believe expression can be simplified somehow.

Comment: Point $1$ is enough : you can compare with a geometric series now . Look up the ratio test.

Comment: You have proven convergence and you are done. Why would you need to "simplify" ?

Comment: Great question, since i see that the numerator can be converted to n+9!, therefore we can assume that the author assumed a different solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in comments, you do not need to simplify.

However, if you wish a nice form, write
$$x_n=\prod_{k=1}^n \frac {k+9}{2k-1}=\frac{\prod_{k=1}^n (k+9) } {\prod_{k=1}^n (2k-1) }=\frac {\Gamma (n+10)}{9!} \frac{\sqrt{\pi } }{2^n\,\Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}$$ Now, taking logarithms, using Stirling approximation of the gamma function and continuing with Taylor expansions, you could show that
$$\log(x_n)=-n \log(2)+\frac{19 }{2}\log (n)+\log \left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{9!}\right)+O\left(\frac{1}{p}\right)$$

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\frac {n+9} {2n-1} <\frac  3 4$ for $n >20$. Using the fact that $(\frac 3 4)^{n} \to 0$ you can conclude that $x_n \to 0$.

[$0 <x_n <(\frac  {10} 1) (\frac  {11} 3)...(\frac  {29} {39})(\frac 3  4)^{n-20}$ for $ n >20$].